Need help identifying component with 'T4 G4' markings
I need help with identifying a Yaskawa Z1000 board component (T4 G4 markings on):


Please add rough dimensions just to confirm package type

Need dimensions and package size.

It's likely a Diodes Inc. BAV16W or 1N4148W fast switching diode in a SOD123 package.
The following marking information is shown in the datasheet.

The horizontal T4 marking is the product code (indicates 1N4148 or BAV16W, same thing really). The vertical G4 is a date code indicating April 2019.
